# join 5 mysql queries

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-logic

Hi I have below 5 mysql queries, i want to see output of all queries in by executing a single query.
please let me know how can i join all these queries.

1.

```
select sum(msu) 
from wgr_raw 
where dt 
between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-07';
```

2.

```
select * 
from wgr_raw 
where dt 
between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-07' 
order by dt;
```

3.

```
select admin,sum(msu) 
from wgr_raw 
where dt 
between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-07' 
group by admin;
```

4.

```
SELECT admin, sum(msu) 
from wgr_raw 
where dt 
between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-07' 
group by admin 
order by msu desc 
limit 25; 

Select ADMIN1,WEEK1,WEEK2,WEEK3,
       (((WEEK3-WEEK2)/WEEK2)*100) as percentage_change, 
         (WEEK3-WEEK2) as MSU_Difference 
from 
       ((select admin as ADMIN1, sum(msu) as WEEK1 
         from wgr_raw 
         where dt >= date_sub(date('2013-11-01'), 
             INTERVAL 25 DAY) and dt < date_sub(date('2013-11-07'), 
             INTERVAL 18 DAY) 
         group by admin 
         order by WEEK1) as q1,
       (select admin as ADMIN2, sum(msu) as WEEK2 
        from wgr_raw 
        where dt >= date_sub(date('2013-11-01'), 
             INTERVAL 18 DAY) and dt < date_sub(date('2013-11-07'), 
             INTERVAL 11 DAY) 
         group by admin 
         order by WEEK2) as q2,
       (select admin as ADMIN3, sum(msu) as WEEK3 
        from wgr_raw where dt >= date_sub(date('2013-11-01'), 
             INTERVAL 11 DAY) and dt < date_sub(date('2013-11-07'), 
             INTERVAL 4 DAY) 
         group by admin 
         order by WEEK3) as q3)  
where ADMIN1=ADMIN3 and ADMIN2=ADMIN3 
group by admin1 
order by WEEK1 desc 
limit 25;
```

5.

```
select dt,sum(msu) 
from wgr_raw 
where dt >= date_sub(date('2013-11-01'), 
   INTERVAL 11 DAY) 
group by dt 
limit 7;
```

Comment: You need to provide the complete table structure and the referential key between these tables.

Comment: use semicolon after each query and fire

Comment: @SEBBINFIELD not going to work because he's got different number columns in most of the queries.

Comment: @booyaa Correct, now the post is in better format i can see all of the  query.

Comment: Table has 3 columns  
1.  dt  Type-Date  
2.  admin Type-varchar(20)  
3.  msu Type-int(20)

Answer (score 1):

You can merge n number of select queries using `UNION` but there is one condition in UNION. Your all select fields should be same and order by will be common.

```
(
    (SELECT a, b FROM tbl WHERE id >= 50 and id <= 100)
    UNION
    (SELECT a, b FROM tbl WHERE id >= 150 and id <= 200)
    UNION
    (SELECT a, b FROM tbl WHERE id >= 250 and id <= 300)
    UNION
    (SELECT a, b FROM tbl WHERE id >= 350 and id <= 400)

)
ORDER BY a
```